# Matlab: How to read data into a matrix

Tags: matlab, file, matrix

I have a data file `matrix.txt`, it has three columns. The first column stores the row index, the second column stores the column index, the third column stores the value. How do I read these into a matrix called `mat`. To be explicit, suppose our `mat` is a `n*n` square matrix, let `n=2` for instance. In the text file, it has:

```
0 0 10
1 1 -10
```

The element in `mat` not specified is `0`. Thus `mat` is supposed to be:

```
mat = 10   0
      0   -10
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is it known that the matrix is square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for the generic 2-D case.

```
% Read in matrix specification
fID = fopen('matrix.txt');
tmp = fscanf(fID, '%u%u%f', [3 inf])';
fclose(fID);

% Use the maximum row and column subscripts to obtain the matrix size
tmp(:, 1:2) = tmp(:, 1:2) + 1;  % MATLAB doesn't use 0-based indexing
matsize = [max(tmp(:,1)), max(tmp(:,2))];

% Convert subscripts to linear indices
lidx = sub2ind(matsize, tmp(:,1), tmp(:,2));

mat = zeros(matsize);  % Initialize matrix
mat(lidx) = tmp(:,3);  % Assign data
```

Using a sample `matrix.txt`:

```
0 0 10
1 1 -10
1 2 20
```

We receive:

```
>> mat

mat =

    10     0     0
     0   -10    20
```

Answer (score 1):

Since in MATLAB, indices begin with 1 (not zero), we should add 1 to our indices in code.
`r` and `c` stand for row and column.
Also`m` and `n` is for m by n zero matrix

```
A = importdata('matrix.txt');
r = A(:, 1)';
c = A(:, 2)';
m = max(r);
n = max(c);
B = zeros(m + 1, n + 1);
for k = 1:size(A,1);
    B(r(k) + 1, c(k) + 1) = A(k, 3);
end
```

Result:

```
B =

    10     0
     0   -10
```

Answer (score 1):

I see I am too slow, but I decided post my answer anyway...
I initialized matrix A as a vector, and used reshape:

```
%Load all file to matrix at once
%You may consider using fopen and fscanf, in case Matrix.txt is not ordered perfectly.
row_column_val = load('Matrix.txt', '-ascii');

R = row_column_val(:, 1) + 1; %Get vector of row indexes (add 1 - convert to Matalb indeces).
C = row_column_val(:, 2) + 1; %Get vector of column indexes (add 1 - convert to Matalb indeces).
V = row_column_val(:, 3);     %Get vector of values.

nrows = max(R); %Number of rows in matrix.
ncols = max(C); %Number of columns in matrix.

A = zeros(nrows*ncols, 1); %Initialize A as a vector instead of a matrix (length of A is nrows*ncols).

%Put value v in place c*ncols + r for all elements of V, C and R.
%The formula is used for column major matrix (Matlab stored matrices in column major format).
A((C-1)*nrows + R) = V;

A = reshape(A, [nrows, ncols]);
```